# How do dynamic and value types work?

Tags: c#, .net

There is a small piece of code that I can not understand:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ts = new TestStruct() { a = 2 };
        object ots = ts;
        dynamic dts = ots;
        ts.a = 6;
        dts.a = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(dts.GetType()); //Type is TestStruct
        Console.WriteLine("ts.a =" + ts.a); //6
        Console.WriteLine("unboxed ts.a =" + ((TestStruct)ots).a); //4
        Console.WriteLine("dts.a =" + dts.a); //4
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public struct TestStruct
{
    public int a;
}
```

`dts` and `ots` refer to the same variable on the heap, but `GetType` returns for `dts` `TestStruct`. `dts` is `TestStruct` but stored on the heap? Or something I do not understand?

Comment: Why do you think they refer to the same variable? Why do you think it matters where they are stored? Can you explain what you expect to see and why you expect that?

Comment: after dts.a = 4;  (TestStruct)ots).a will return 4, so i think they refer the same variable.
I expected to see unboxing in this line of code dts.a = 4;

Comment: _[Would you like to know more?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

`dts` and `ots` point to the same, boxed, copy of `ts`. `ts` contains the original `TestStruct` separately.

---

As you may know, [*Boxing and unboxing*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) works like this:

> A key difference from the same operations on class types is that boxing and unboxing copies the struct value either into or out of the boxed instance. Thus, following a boxing or unboxing operation, changes made to the unboxed struct are not reflected in the boxed struct.

So in this line:

```
object ots = ts;
```

You are effectively making a copy of your `struct`, and it becomes a reference type. You have now two instances of `TestStruct`. On, original `ts`, and the second one, a copy, which is also a reference type (boxed `TestStruct`). Hence, after this line:

```
dynamic dts = ots;
```

the boxed copy of `ts` is pointed to by two references: `ots` and `dts`. The fact that `dts` is `dynamic` is irrelevant here. What [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) does, is only deferring type checking until run time, and after this, it behaves just like `object`:

> The compiler packages together information about the operation, and that information is later used to evaluate the operation at run time. As part of the process, variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore, type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at run time.

You can observe this happening when going step by step through the code in the debugger and inspecting the values of `ts.GetHashCode()`, `ots.GetHashCode()` and `dts.GetHashCode()`. The actual copying may take place not immediately but after you modify the struct.

Comment: Thanks, i know about boxing/unboxing. I was confused by dts.GetType().It returned TestStruсt type and I thought that the dts is ValueType variable.

Comment: @Frinkie Oh, ok. I'll add an expanation concerning the dynamic keyword then, so it will match your question better.